# How to get the execution graph of a created topology in Apache Storm?

Tags: java, distributed-computing, apache-storm, complex-event-processing, stream-processing

Say, I have a very complex **Apache Storm topology** that is created randomly for some experiments and results in an `StormTopology` object.

I am now interested in the execution graph of this topology (how does it look like?)

But to best of my knowledge, there is no simple way to easily obtain the graph structure back from storm. For sure, there are some approaches that have their downsides:

1. I can scan the `StormTopology`-Object and find bolts and spouts objects, that are containing some **Stream** and **Input**-Objects. But using their `toString()`- in my own logging, for the Spouts, I get something like this. I can`t see, how to rebuild the execution graph from it:

```
"mybolt1": {
        "inputs": {
          "GlobalStreamId(componentId:spout1, streamId:default)": "<Grouping shuffle:NullStruct()>"
        },
        "streams": {
          "s1": "StreamInfo(output_fields:[value], direct:false)",
          "s1__punctuation": "StreamInfo(output_fields:[__punctuation], direct:false)"
        }
```

By the way, what is meant with *Punctuation* here?

2. At some old blog posts and in the documentation, the **Storm Visualization** is mentioned. But since I cannot find any current information to that, I assume that this feature is not supported anymore.

**So my question is: How can I rebuild the execution graph (the format does not matter) from a given `StormTopology`?** I am mainly interested in the arrangement of included bolts and spouts.

Answer (score 0):

The topology visualization should be available in Storm UI as of v0.9.2, see the [release notes](https://storm.apache.org/2014/06/25/storm092-released.html). I don't think the feature has been removed, the [2.2.0 release notes](https://storm.apache.org/2020/06/30/storm220-released.html) still mention the Storm UI visualizer in a few bug fixes.

Comment: Thanks! I have then that too, but I am not able to find any further information or instructions on how to use/create this visualization. Any ideas?

Comment: @moosehead42 You have to go to the Storm UI, click on the topology name, and from there you should see the "Topology Visualization" section, where you can click "Show Visualization"

Comment: Thanks. But what is exactly meant with "punctuation" in the StormTopology-Object?

Comment: Looks like it's for setting up a separate stream for ALL groupings. https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/b6e7d0355e0397b8acc566961ed31279338998e1/storm-client/src/jvm/org/apache/storm/streams/ProcessorBoltDelegate.java#L131-L136